# Printing slashed zero

Tags: java

Can any one give me an idea how to print slashed zero (crossed zero) in java 
I tried this :

But it didn't work for me.

```
    System.out.println((char) 155);
```

Comment: "Didn't work for me" is usually an indication for a bad question. Please be more specific; for example by output that you received.

Comment: Why do you think this should work?

Further information may be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slashed_zero#Representation_in_Unicode_and_HTML

Comment: just for the record, it's not a zero, it's the letter o with some accent, used in nordic languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java uses [Unicode Table](http://unicode-table.com), not ASCII and in Unicode [`155`](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=155) is not `ø` but *Control Sequence Introducer*. So if you search this table you will find that

- [`Ø`](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=%C3%98) can be represented as `U+00D8` or `&#216;`
- [`ø`](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=%C3%B8) can be represented as `U+00F8` or `&#248;`

So you can try with

```
System.out.println('\u00D8');//Ø
System.out.println('\u00F8');//ø

System.out.println((char)216);//Ø
System.out.println((char)248);//ø
```

or if encoding of your file allows it simply

```
System.out.println('Ø');
System.out.println('ø');
```

Answer (score 1):

`248` works.

```
System.out.println((char)248);
```

prints `ø`.

If you want to find out which code corresponds to which char, do the reverse thing and cast the `char` to `int`:

```
System.out.println((int)'ø');
```

prints `248`.

Answer (score 1):

`String s = "\u00D8";` is one way.

`\u00D8` is a *unicode literal* for a slashed zero. A lower case slashed zero is `"\u00F8"`.

Comment: There is a lower case zero?

Comment: @SalmanA that's because it's not a zero, it's an o with accent so to speak -- used in nordic languages.